# Is there way to compute the covariance matrix of polynomial fit coefficients using dlib in C++?

Tags: python, c++, regression, dlib

I have some code that uses the **numpy** function `p, cov = np.polyfit(x=x_data, y=y_data, deg=2, cov=True)` in python to estimate a model from some data as well as the covariance matrix of the fit. I need to translate this python code to C++ using **dlib**.

The `dlib::solve_least_squares` function computes the model coefficients from my data correctly. However, I can't seem to find a way to also compute the covariance matrix. Is there a function in **dlib** to do this or do I need to compute them from scratch using matrix operations?

Comment: All these mathematical terms sound scaring to me. However, if nothing else helps you could try to resemble what is done in `numpy.polyfit()`. `numpy` is open source and available on github: [`numpy.polyfit()`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/polynomial/polynomial.py#L1190) which has a lot of doc but only one line of code `return pu._fit(polyvander, x, y, deg, rcond, full, w)` => [`polyutils._fit()`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/polynomial/polyutils.py#L641)